# What is the rules of this site?

Tags: discussion

What are the rules for this site since I keep getting my questions closed from the rules I want to know so I can avoid breaking these rules

Comment: I am sorry for using a non explaining tag since there was no tag about this site I am very sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some general advice: the Help Center articles [What topics can I ask about here?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (which is site-specific) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) (which is a network-wide template) contain most of the things you need to know in order to avoid your question getting closed. The [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) and [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) tags often contain questions about the details/edge cases of what is on-topic and off-topic for a site.

If I look at [your account](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/58980/fluffydaboy), I see one duplicate question (you can often, but not always, avoid those by [searching](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search) before posting a question), one question which was migrated here to Meta (i.e. this one) and a question which has a negative score but is not closed. You mention "I keep getting my questions closed from the rules" but that must be deleted questions then. I can't see them, and I'm not a regular here so I can't really go into details.

As for the question with negative score, @Turamarth correctly mentions they all came during the [first revision of the question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/revisions/61976/1) which to be honest was quite unclear.

[image]

Comment: I think the negative vote one was also closed at some point. Though I'm still a bit baffled as to why that question is so negatively received.

Comment: The [timeline](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/61976/timeline) shows somebody flagged it for closure, but a moderator voted to keep it open.

Comment: @DJPirtu according to the timeline the three downvotes came during the first version of the question which was missing the link to the video and was therefore quite unclear.